# Test database for audit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, audit

I have added audit rails gem in my project and its working fine with the development rails. I had few test cases written before that, which were running. After adding audit gem, i changed my audited.yml file and added test database, but still while running rspec I'm getting following error:

> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:
>           FATAL:  database "audit_test" does not exist
>   How to resolve the above error.

Comment: try `rake db:test:create` and run specs again

Answer (score 0):

In case you already did

```
$ rails generate audited:install
$ rake db:migrate
```

You only have to do

```
$ rake db:test:prepare
```